# creating auto increment alphanumeric number using sql

Tags: mysql, database

[image]

Currently the client inserts the the number themselves in the format which is shown in the image. Now they want it to be done automatically. I researched a lot but couldn't get any idea . Help me out with this one.. how can i have the auto increment in the way given in the image

Comment: Auto increment columns in MySQL must be integer.

Comment: Check this link i think so helpfull you-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17668987/auto-increment-alphanumeric-id-in-mssql

Comment: create stored procedure or user defined function

Comment: Define 'alphanumeric number'. Do you mean hexadecimal? Base-36? Base-64?

Comment: You can use regular auto increment, and make the translation (e.g. from `105A` to `211)` in the `view` layer.